# Using present perfect continuous

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, perfect-constructions

One of the uses of present perfect continuous is:

> **One continuing event**
>
> We use the present perfect continuous for a single activity that began at a point in the past and is still continuing:
>
> Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/present-perfect-continuous-i-have-been-working)

Now, imagine this situation, I am working as web developer in a company...:

> Boss: I am really disappointed with your project.
>
> Me: Which is the reason for that?
>
> Boss: The reason is all. Your project is so bad.
>
> Me: Let me tell you something, **I have been working on this project one year approximately** and you only told me that my project is so bad without any given reason.

My question: When I said "I have been working on this project one year approximately", **Am I expressing time in that tense correctly?** I will explain what I mean, for example: I worked as football trainer two year **ago** approximately. In that example I finished my activity two year ago approximately, but in the first example of this paragraph the activity began in the past and is still continuing, I did not use **ago**, for me ago sounds like past (started/finished in the past), I do not know if I am right or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I have been working on the project for  one year**

The sentence means  you started working on the project one year ago and you are still working and probably you will be working in the future too.

You should not say**I have been working on the project  for one year ago**..

You can say.

**I have been  working on the project for one  year now**